# Convert "???? ??????" in to arabic language

Tags: ios, iphone, sql-server

I am getting data from remote sql server like this 
.

> "USER_NAME" = "???? ??????";

I have to get value of username in arabic language but I am getting ??????. 
I have navchar type of text filed at database. 
I am using these lines of code:-

```
NSString *output = [[feed objectForKey:@"USER_NAME"] stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding];
                NSLog(@"%@",output);
```

So How can I fixed this?

Comment: More information is needed. How do you get the `feed` object from the server (show your code)? What format and encoding does the server use to send the response?

Comment: @MartinR ok. I am using private libraries to access remote sql sever and i am getting this result from data base.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can be two possible reasons for sql server to show some unicode data like `????????`

> Reason 1.  
>  when unicode data wan inserted or updated to that
>   column the user didnt prefix the string with `N`.
>
> Reason 2.  
>  The Column itself isnt NVARCHAR means it doesnt allow
>   storing unicode characters to be stored.

Example

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE 
(Column1 VARCHAR(100),         --<-- VARCHAR DataType
Column2 NVARCHAR(100),         --<-- NVARCHAR DataType
Column3 NVARCHAR(100)COLLATE  Arabic_CI_AS   --<-- NVARCHAR DataType with specific
)                                               -- arabic collation

INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES
('هذا هو العربي','هذا هو العربي', 'هذا هو العربي'),    -- Data with out N Prefix
(N'هذا هو العربي',N'هذا هو العربي', N'هذا هو العربي')  -- Data with  N Prefix

SELECT * FROM @TABLE
```

**Result**

```
╔═══════════════╦═══════════════╦═══════════════╗
║    Column1    ║    Column2    ║    Column3    ║
╠═══════════════╬═══════════════╬═══════════════╣
║ ??? ?? ?????? ║ ??? ?? ?????? ║ ??? ?? ?????? ║
║ ??? ?? ?????? ║ هذا هو العربي ║ هذا هو العربي ║
╚═══════════════╩═══════════════╩═══════════════╝
```

Only data Where Column allows unicode characters to be stored and when I used N prefix will have data stored in the rest are only showing ???????.

In your case you have simply lost the data you cannot possibly convert it back to unicode / Arabic characters . Ouch :S

Comment: I am using this lib to connect remote sql server [sql](http://objcsharp.wordpress.com/2013/10/15/an-open-source-sql-server-library-for-ios/). There he is using NTBSTRINGBIND to bind column and SYBCHAR

Comment: @user3094994 : does you IOS support Arabic?