# How to see Arabic characters entered into SQL Server instead of?

Tags: sql-server, encoding, arabic, collation

I have a client who inserted some Arabic text into SQL Server database column. Now the text displays as ????? only.

I know that this is related to collation and that he should have modified the collation of SQL Server before entering his data. Also I know that he should have used nVarchar, instead of Varchar in his column.

How can I retrieve the data entered in his column or convert it into Arabic from ???? since the data is already entered and we need to convert it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Two things to ensure: **(1)** the column's datatype **must be** `nvarchar(n)` - and **(2)** when inserting string literals from SQL code, you **must prefix** that string literal with a `N` prefix. Once the data is entered wrongly - it's "dead"- you cannot "fix it"  - you need to wipe it out, change the column datatype to `nvarchar(n)`, and then re-insert the data from the source

Comment: so we can't retrieve the data?

Comment: As I said - once stored wrongly - it's gone, you **cannot** retrieve / restore it. You've been storing 2-byte-per character data into a single byte - you cannot revert that process, it's just plain impossible

Answer (score 0):

Here are some basic rules which you may want to keep in mind. While storing Unicode data, the column must be of Unicode data type (nchar, nvarchar, ntext). Another rule is that the value must be prefixed with N while insertion like the below.

```
INSERT INTO TBL_LANG VALUES ('English',N'I am American')

INSERT INTO TBL_LANG VALUES ('Tamil',N'நான் தமிழன்')
```

If the data inserted in the correct manner, then you will get the correct response.

As well have a look at the link.
[Convert “???? ??????” in to arabic language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21203330/convert-in-to-arabic-language)

Comment: Another rule is: don't insert literals from user input as this can cause SQL injection. Use parameters instead

Comment: So can't we retrieve the data?

Comment: `ntext` and `text` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)` or `varchar(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Comment: @Ahmad If it is stored in the correct format, Then we can retrieve the correct data